# How does the kjv translate Amos 4:4?

Tags: hebrew, translation-philosophy, amos, tithes

KJV Amos 4 : 4

> Come to Beth-el, and transgress; at Gilgal multiply transgression; and bring your sacrifices every morning, and ***your tithes after three years***:

באו בית אל ופשעו הגלגל הרבו לפשע והביאו לבקר
זבחיכם לשלשת ימים מעשרתיכם׃

The Hebrew phrase לשלשת ימים  seemingly refers to every three days rather than years

So how did the translaters get years in the above text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that the operative Hebrew word in Amos 4:4 is יָמִ֖ים = "days".  Modern versions are quite divided about whether this should be translated as "days" or "years", as are many commentators.

I am no defender of the KJV, but let me demonstrate PERHAPS why the KJV translators chose "years" rather than the literal, "days".

**1. Allusion to Deut 14:28**

Amos 4:4 may be an indirect allusion to

> Deut 14:28 - “At the end of every **three years** you shall bring out
> all the tithe of your produce in the same year and lay it up within
> your towns.

> Deut 26:12 - “When you have finished paying all the tithe of your
> produce in the third year, which is the year of tithing, giving it to
> the Levite, the sojourner, the fatherless, and the widow, so that they
> may eat within your towns and be filled,

**2. Day for Year**

The Hebrew idiom often uses "day" when a literal year is intended, for example:

- Numerous references in the Genesis 5 genealogies have the oft repeated formula, “And all the days of xxx were yyy years…” etc, more than 20 times in this chapter alone.
- Ex 13:10 – The Passover was to be observed “from days to days” clearly meaning “year after year” as most versions correctly have it.
- Judges 17:10 - And Micah said to him, “Stay with me, and be to me a father and a priest, and I will give you ten pieces of silver **per year** and a suit of clothes and your living.” And the Levite went in. [The "year" here is actually "day"]
- Lev 25:29 - “If a man sells a dwelling house in a walled city, he may redeem it within a year of its sale. For a **full year** he shall have the right of redemption. ["year" here is actually, "day".]
- 1 Sam 2:19 – Hannah took Samuel a new robe “from days to days” clearly meaning “year after year”, or, “each year” as most versions correctly have it.
- 1 Sam 20:6 – David asked to be excused from the “sacrifice of the days” clearly meaning “annual sacrifice” as most versions correctly have it.
- 1 Sam 27:7 – David dwelt in the land of the Philistines “days and four months” clearly meaning “a year and four months” as most versions correctly have it.

There are many more to quote but this sample shows the pattern.

**3. Day and Year Parallel**

Isa 34:8, 61:2, 63:4, Job 10:5, 15:20, 36:11, Ps 39:5, 61:6, 90:10, 15, Eze 22:4, etc.  These references use “year” and “day” interchangeably in the Hebrew, usually in Hebrew parallelism.

None of this is complete justification for the KJV translation.  The NKJV has "days".

Answer (score 1):

*Young's Concordance* clearly shows that the Hebrew word *'yamim'* occurs in Amos 4:4, ***which can also be taken to mean 'yearly', or 'many days'*** . For instance, in 1 Kings 1:1 the KJV reads, "Now king David was old [and] stricken in years." It could have been translated "stricken in days", because the word generally used for 'years' is *shanah*, but that is not in the text of the KJV at 1 Kings 1:1. It is *yamim*, generally translated 'days'. But translating the word for 'days' as 'years' makes perfect sense here.

Young's Concordance also shows that the Hebrew word *'shanah'* occurs in Deuteronomy 14:28 and 26:12, where it means 'the third year' and this certainly shows the difficulty asked about. If *'shanah'* had been in Amos 4:4 there would have been no difficulty, but the word for 'days' is used, not the word for years.

However, there is a footnote for Amos 4:4 in the *NIV Study Bible* (1987 edition) which, like the KJV, translates the verse as "...your tithes every three years". It comments:

> "*tithes*.  Apparently the special tithe that was to be brought every
> three years (cf. Dt. 14:28; 26:12). *years.*  See NIV text note [which
> gives the alternative reading of *'tithes on the third day'*]. The
> Hebrew word for 'days' sometimes stands for years." p. 1330

But perhaps the most interesting footnote for Amos 4:4 is in the *NLT Study Bible* (2008 edition) which translates the phrase as "bring your tithes every three days". It comments regarding verses 4 and 5:

> "The prophet's sarcasm shows how far Israel had strayed from God's
> ways. Israel had plenty of religion but no reverence for God. Amos
> lampoons the Israelites' worthless piety...
>
> Israelite males were to appear before the Lord at the sanctuary three
> times each year. Tithes were typically paid annually with a special
> tithe paid every three years. Amos is making the point that the
> Israelites were religious to the point of absurdity, but they balked
> at being godly." p. 1458

That might be why this translation puts verse 5 as, "Then give your extra voluntary offerings so you can brag about it everywhere. This is the kind of thing you Israelites love to do." Interestingly, in this section they give a literal 'days' rendering while the NIV and the KJV go for 'years', yet they all include the way God knows all about their many religious performances, and that they love to do those things despite never having returned to the Lord. Therefore, they are warned: "Prepare to meet thy God, O Israel" (vs. 12).

Whether those particular tithes were every three years, or every three days, the gist of the whole passage remains clear, especially given how 1 Kings 1:1 can properly be translated as either many years, or many days. The NLT does not use either, but gives its own equivalence of, "King David was now very old" despite saying in the footnote that David was actually 70 years of age (2 Samuel 5:4-5).